# Logarithm Question (Find x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to solve x for $$x^{2\log_{10}x}=\frac{x^5}{100}$$?

Comment: Edit your post to include what you have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll write $\log$ for $\log_{10}$. Take the $\log$ of both sides. You get

$$2\log(x)^2 = 5\log(x) - 2.$$

Now let $y = \log(x)$. You have a quadratic equation
$$
2y^2 - 5y + 2 = 0
$$
which you can factor as
$$
(2y - 1)(y-2) = 0.
$$
So $y = 2$ or $y = 1/2$, so $x = 100$ or $x = \sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Why the Alpha Wolfram only shows x=100?

Comment: i probably made a mistake factoring the polynomial.

Comment: no i didn't, it's a solution (just plug it in) -- not sure why wolfram doesn't see it.

Comment: I know why. Wolfram Alpha just shows the integer solution

Comment: It solved it for me... [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E%282*log_10+%28x%29%29%3Dx%5E5%2F100.+)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $$x^{2\log_{10}x}=\frac{x^5}{100}$$

Take $log_x$ of both sides of the equation.

Notice that: $log_{x}10 = \frac{1}{log_{10}x}$; and now solve!

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to solve . we can assume that $x^{2\log_{10}x}=x$
Then we find that$(2\log_{10}x}=1)$
Finally $x=\sqrt{10}$

Comment: Why can we assume that?

Comment: It give us the same answer if we did that . and you have to check that at the two sides

Answer (score 0):

An alternative basically identical to @hunter's solution would be to suppose a solution of the form $x=10^k$.

Substituting, we get:

$10^{2k^2}=10^{5k-2}$;

The transformation $10^{\cdot}$ is 1-1, so the solution for $k$ solves the quadratic $2k^2-5k+2=0$ with solutions $k=\frac{1}{2},2$.